# monerod is sync or not?

Tags: monerod, database

Is my monerod database sync or not?

> status
> Height: 1554546/1554546 (100.0%) on mainnet, not mining, net
> hash 502.65 MH/s, v7, up to date, 8(out)+1(in)  connections, uptime 0d
> 0h 2m 14s 2018-04-19 09:57:49.516
>
> [P2P4]  INFO    global
> src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:310
> [113.240.xxx.yyy:47738 INC] Sync data returned a new top block
> candidate: 1554548 -> 1554739 [Your node is 191 blocks (0 days)
> behind] SYNCHRONIZATION started
>
> status Height: 1554552/1554552
> (100.0%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 508.09 MH/s, v7, up to date,
> 7(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 14m 47s 2018-04-19 10:12:16.673
>
> [P2P0]  INFO    global
> src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:310
> [163.172.73.21:57694 INC] Sync data returned a new top block
> candidate: 1554552 -> 1554965 [Your node is 413 blocks (0 days)
> behind] SYNCHRONIZATION started

After restart monerod I have info:

> 2018-04-19 10:16:18.889 [P2P4]  INFO    global
> src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1557
> SYNCHRONIZED OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way to check whether the sync has completed is to check the current block height using a block explorer (e.g. https://moneroblocks.info) and then check to see whether your status height is the same as that shown on the block explorer.

Comment: And how to refer to this: according the data from the host 163.172.73.21, the last block has the number 1554965.
Information is from 2018-04-19 around 10:00 am and according to moneroblocks timestam for 1554965 2018-04-20 00:26:34 UTC.